# How can I make Django slug and id work together?

Tags: django, django-urls, slug, slugify

I want my URL to contain both id and slug like StackOverflow, but the slug is not working properly. Instead of being like this:

```
www.example.com/games/155/far-cry-5
```

the URL is like this:

```
www.example.com/games/155/<bound%20method%20Game.slug%20of%20<Game:%20Far%20Cry%205>>
```

My models.py :

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def slug(self):
        return slugify(self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:gamedetail', kwargs={'pk': self.id, 'slug': self.slug})
```

My views.py :

```
class GameDetail(DetailView):
    model = Game
    template_name = 'core/game_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'game_detail'
```

My urls.py :

```
path('<int:pk>/<slug>', views.GameDetail.as_view(), name='gamedetail')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the slug() method to get the value.

```
return reverse('core:gamedetail', kwargs={'pk': self.id, 'slug': self.slug()})
```

Or define it as a propery of the class

```
@property
def slug(self):
    ...
```